# Неотображаемое окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт с темой TwentyTwenty-child

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(смотри https://dbmast.ru/adaptivnye-modalnye-formy-vhoda-i-registracii ).

В файле `header.php` ссылка Вход|Регистрация имеет вид

```html
                            <div class="entrylink">
                                    <a href='javascript: document.location.href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/entry.php"'>
                                        <span class="eEkWAa">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/useentryicon.png" class="myalign">
                                            </img>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="gxtXIp"><?php echo " " ?>Вход</span>
                                        <span class="bidiEP">|</span>
                                        <span class="jCpPzc"> Регистрация</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
```

Эта ссылка ведет в файл `entry.php`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Gem style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
    
    <title>Адаптивные модальные формы входа и регистрации</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <div id="cd-logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>

        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <!-- ссылки на вызов форм -->
                <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div class="cd-intro">
        <h1>Модальные Формы Вход / Регистрация</h1>
        <div class="cd-nugget-info">
            <a href="http://dbmast.ru/adaptivnye-modalnye-formy-vhoda-i-registracii">
                &larr; Статья &amp; Скачать
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- все формы на фоне затемнения-->
        <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- основной контейнер -->
            <ul class="cd-switcher">
                <li><a href="#0">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cd-login"> <!-- форма входа -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Пароль</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Пароль">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Скрыть</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
                        <label for="remember-me">Запомнить меня</label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Войти">
                    </p>
                </form>
                
                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Забыли свой пароль?</a></p>
                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-login -->

            <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- форма регистрации -->
                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Имя пользователя</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signup-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signup-password">Пароль</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-password" type="text"  placeholder="Пароль">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Скрыть</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms">
                        <label for="accept-terms">Я согласен с <a href="#0">Условиями</a></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Создать аккаунт">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <!-- <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Close</a> -->
            </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

            <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- форма восстановления пароля -->
                <p class="cd-form-message">Забыли пароль? Пожалуйста, введите адрес своей электронной почты. Вы получите ссылку, чтобы создать новый пароль.</p>

                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Здесь сообщение об ошибке!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Восстановить пароль">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Вернуться к входу</a></p>
            </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
            <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Закрыть</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Gem jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

После щелчка на ссылке Вход|Регистрация возникают следующие окна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После удаления из entry.php следующего кода

```html
    <header role="banner">
        <div id="cd-logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a></div>

        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <!-- ссылки на вызов форм -->
                <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <div class="cd-intro">
        <h1>Модальные Формы Вход / Регистрация</h1>
        <div class="cd-nugget-info">
            <a href="http://dbmast.ru/adaptivnye-modalnye-formy-vhoda-i-registracii">
                &larr; Статья &amp; Скачать
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

и после нажатия на ссылку Вход|Регистрация на экран выскакивает пустое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что это за файла entry.php ? какое он вообще отношение к теме имеет?

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev прояснил значение `entry.php`?

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev вы поняли - какое значение имеет файл entry.php?